# The nested loop cannot be stopped

Tags: r

I'm testing a nested loop. The idea is to first loop through i and k, add them up, and loop through j (j has to be not equal to k). The loop runs for so long that I have to manually stop the loop. Since it's a small data, I know it shouldn't take that long, but can't figure out where it goes wrong. Below is the sample data.

```
test = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), s= c(0.4,0.3,0.3), j1 = c(0.3,0.22,0.15), j2 = c(0.11,0.58, 0.02))
```

This is the code:

```
j = 1
k = 1

firstsum = 0
tm1 <- system.time(
  while (j <= nrow(test)){
    while (k <= nrow(test)){
      if (k == j) {
        next
      } else {
        for (i in 3:4){

          normindator = normindator + (test[j,i] * test[k, i])
          denominator = denominator + test[j, i] * test[j, i]
          firstsum = firstsum + norminator/denominator * test[k, 2]
          k = k + 1
          normindator = 0
          denominator = 0
        }
      }
    }
    secondsum = 0
    secondsum = secondsum + firstsum * test[j,2]
    j = j + 1
    k = 1
  }
)
```

Comment: if `k == j` you don't increment `k` - i believe that could be your issue

Comment: @Warrior, when you debug a loop try to add something like `print(k)` or `print(j)`. It's somewhat lazy way to debug, but that way you will be able to know where your loop at.

Comment: @DJV thank you. New to R loops, I just found the print is a good way to debug.

Comment: also, `browser()` is a very helpful debugging tool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `next` skipped the increment of `k`. Try this version of your loop

```
test = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), s= c(0.4,0.3,0.3), j1 = c(0.3,0.22,0.15), j2 = c(0.11,0.58, 0.02))


j = 1
k = 1

firstsum = 0
tm1 <- system.time(
  while (j <= nrow(test)){
    while (k <= nrow(test)){
      if (k != j) {
        for (i in 3:4){
          normindator = 0
          denominator = 0

          normindator = normindator + (test[j,i] * test[k, i])
          denominator = denominator + test[j, i] * test[j, i]
          firstsum = firstsum + normindator/denominator * test[k, 2]

        }
      }
      k = k + 1
    }
    secondsum = 0
    secondsum = secondsum + firstsum * test[j,2]
    j = j + 1
    k = 1
  }
)
```